# How to redirect the page if access it directly using PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

I have 2 php pages. 1st, is for login form and the 2nd php page is the information.

I want the 2nd php page only accessible if the user redirect from the 1st page redirect and prevent the user from accessing it directly.

Let's say the 1st php file called "form.php" and the 2nd php file that I want to prevent direct access called "info.php".

Any suggestions?

So far, see my code below (my code is not working) I got white blank page

Form.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if((isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != '') && (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '')){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];

    $loginform = (strlen($_SESSION["username"])>0 && strlen($_SESSION["email"])>0);
     if($loginform){
       $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
       echo("<script>location.href = '/info/';</script>");
     }
   }
}
```

info.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']){
    echo("<script>location.href = '/login/';</script>");
}
```

Comment: do you want only login users should access info.php page?

Comment: Yes, if the user already have a session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start `session` at `login.php` page if `login` success and set a `session` `variable` just befor the `header` in `login.php`.

```
login.php

<?php
session_start();// at top of page
..... after login means all your query running
if(querysuccess){
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
header('location:info.php');

}


info.php// here check if session variable not 1 then redirect again to login.php


<?php
session_start();
if(!SESSION['loggedIn']){
header('location:login.php');
}

else{

// just do whatever you want
}
?>
```

**updated answer**

`start` `session` at top of form page

```
<?php
session_start();// should be at top
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if((isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] != '') && (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '')){
        $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];

    $loginform = (strlen($_SESSION["username"])>0 && strlen($_SESSION["email"])>0);
     if($loginform){
       $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
       echo("<script>location.href = '/info/';</script>");
     }
   }
}
```

you forget to close isset in `info.php`. Also start session also here

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    echo("<script>location.href = '/login/';</script>");

}
```

Comment: @user12345 please see my update post with code. my code is not working

Comment: @User014019 please show your code where you set $_SESSION["username"] and $_SESSION["email"]

Comment: @User12345, please see the update code in my post. the $_SESSION for username and email defined in form.php

Answer (score 0):

you can just use header() method in php.

```
header('location:info.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store a flag in session on form.php page and after that first thing check in info.php that whether flag exists in session or not, if yes proceed to info.php. if not redirect back to form.php or die whatever you want.